# Option to extend volume on windows 10 disk management greyed out for no reason

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive, disk-management

Alright, I was trying to use this external 4TB HDD as a live disk for Linux, it worked but now I have to reformat it. However Disk Management, in it's infinite wisdom, has decided to grey out the option to extend the volume for seemingly no reason, with no explanation as to why it's greyed out provided whatsoever. I have not found a single solution for this problem that has no reason to exist that is relevant.
I have tried formatting it again, formatting it as exFAT, formatting the unallocated bit(the option to format that is greyed out too), error checking it, attempting to summon lucifer to figure it out, literally anything I could think of. Please help. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZXjc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Of course literally seconds after posting this, I figure it out. You have to delete the format, right click the box on the far left that says "Disk (Whatever number)", convert to GPT, and *then* format it as NTFS. How intuitive.